# ASP.NET Core Identity - where is Account Controller and Folder

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am new to `.NET Core` and wanted to ask about `Identity`.

I bought a book and followed all the instruction. It is very simple to set `Identity` the way the book describes.
Create an Account Controller, LogIn, Logout views etc...

But when I create a new project with Visual Studio with Individual User Accounts selected.

I can't find the Account Controller folder. There is an Areas folder but almost empty. `Areas\Idnetity\Pages\_ViewStart.html`.

I checked hidden files etc, but couldn't find `Account` or `Identity` Folder.

The login link is like this

```
 https://localhost:44313/Identity/Account/Login
```

`Identity` is working but where are the codes?

Comment: As far as I know it is done via `Razor Pages` and ready assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/) states:

> In ASP.NET Core 2.1 we can now ship Razor UI in reusable class
>   libraries. We are using this feature to provide the entire identity UI
>   as a prebuilt package (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI) that you can
>   simply reference from an application.

Notice that you are asking this feature to be effective by adding `.AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)` to `ConfigureServices` method.

If you still love to scaffold the `Identity` as old days, use this `cli` command:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --useDefaultUI
```

For more information on scaffolding options visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli).

Answer (score 0):

`AccountController` in ASP.NET MVC with `Login`, `Register`, `Logout` and `CreateRole` actions.

```cs
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Register() { return View(); }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVm vm)
    {
        if (!vm.Email.Contains("@")) ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email formatini duzgwn daxil edin");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(vm); }
        AppUser user = new AppUser()
        {
            Name = vm.Name,
            Email = vm.Email,
            Surname = vm.Surname,
            UserName = vm.UserName,
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, vm.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var item in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", item.Description);
            }
            return View(vm);
        }
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRole.Member.ToString());
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home");
    }

    public IActionResult Login() { return View(); }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVm vm, string? returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(vm); }
        AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(vm.UsernameOrEmail) ?? await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.UsernameOrEmail);
        if (user == null) { ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username/Email or Password incorrect"); return View(); }
        var result = _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, vm.Password, true).Result;
        if (result.IsLockedOut) { ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Try again later"); return View(result); }
        if (!result.Succeeded) { ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username/Email or Password incorrect"); }
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, vm.RememberMe);
        return (returnUrl is not null && returnUrl.Contains("Login")) ? RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home") : (ActionResult)Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    public IActionResult Logout() { _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home"); }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole()
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)))
        {
            if (await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(item.ToString()) == null)
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole() { Name = item.ToString() });
            };
        };
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Home");
    }
}

public class RegisterVm
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 2 karekter daxil edebilersiz")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Maxsimum 25 karater daxil ede bilersiz")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 2 karekter daxil edebilersiz")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Maxsimum 25 karater daxil ede bilersiz")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 8 karekter daxil edebilersiz")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Maxsimum 25 karater daxil ede bilersiz")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Comfirm passwordu duzgun daxil edin")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```